# whether the following series converge or diverge

Tags: calculus

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n3^{(n-1)}}$$

Comment: Note that you have a geometric series whose terms are decreasing.

Comment: @Mohammed Alnasiri: Please check that I got the edit right.  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Your series can be written as $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {3}{6^n}.$$
It is a geometric series with $a=3/6=1/2, r=1/6$.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_test):

\[\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n 3^{n-1}}<\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}=1.\]